# ZipFileInputStream read method is delaying the process of marshalling when using StaxEventItemWriter in Spring Batch

Tags: java, xml, spring-batch, marshalling, stax

## Preface

I am using `spring batch` in the `spring-boot` application. The Spring Boot version is `2.3.3.RELEASE`.

I have a `multi-step` job, which validates xml file header in the first step then `read transaction` in `chunk oriented step`, do some `business logic` on each transaction and then `write` it back to `xml` file. In the third and final step I `delete the input file`. My `Chunk size` is set to `500` transactions currently.

### Problem

Everything is working fine ,except the `thread is locked` in `RUNNABLE` state for almost `10 minutes` in `between write and next read`. I took the `thread dump` but could not make much out of it, even though i observed that `thread stack trace` is `same` all the time.

```html
"europeanGateway-3" #90 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x0000023b7d347800 nid=0x6bd0 runnable [0x000000c228cfb000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.read(Native Method)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.access$1400(ZipFile.java:60)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipFileInputStream.read(ZipFile.java:735)
        - locked <0x00000005c037d9e8> (a sun.net.www.protocol.jar.URLJarFile)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipFileInputStream.read(ZipFile.java:750)
        at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:83)
        at java.io.DataInputStream.readByte(DataInputStream.java:265)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.bytecode.ClassTailor.tailor(ClassTailor.java:119)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.opt.AccessorInjector.tailor(AccessorInjector.java:107)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.opt.AccessorInjector.prepare(AccessorInjector.java:68)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.opt.OptimizedAccessorFactory.get(OptimizedAccessorFactory.java:164)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.Accessor$FieldReflection.optimize(Accessor.java:271)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.property.SingleElementLeafProperty.<init>(SingleElementLeafProperty.java:77)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor73.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.property.PropertyFactory.create(PropertyFactory.java:113)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.<init>(ClassBeanInfoImpl.java:166)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getOrCreate(JAXBContextImpl.java:488)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getOrCreate(JAXBContextImpl.java:507)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.property.SingleElementNodeProperty.<init>(SingleElementNodeProperty.java:90)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor74.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.property.PropertyFactory.create(PropertyFactory.java:113)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.<init>(ClassBeanInfoImpl.java:166)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getOrCreate(JAXBContextImpl.java:488)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getOrCreate(JAXBContextImpl.java:507)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.property.SingleElementNodeProperty.<init>(SingleElementNodeProperty.java:90)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor74.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.property.PropertyFactory.create(PropertyFactory.java:113)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.<init>(ClassBeanInfoImpl.java:166)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getOrCreate(JAXBContextImpl.java:488)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.<init>(JAXBContextImpl.java:305)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.<init>(JAXBContextImpl.java:124)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl$JAXBContextBuilder.build(JAXBContextImpl.java:1123)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:147)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor375.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:247)
        at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:234)
        at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(ContextFinder.java:462)
        at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:641)
        at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:584)
        at com.trax.europeangateway.itemwriter.omegaxml.OmegaXmlJaxb2Marshaller.marshalStaxResult(OmegaXmlJaxb2Marshaller.java:50)
        at com.trax.europeangateway.itemwriter.omegaxml.OmegaXmlJaxb2Marshaller.marshal(OmegaXmlJaxb2Marshaller.java:29)
        at org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller.marshal(Jaxb2Marshaller.java:695)
        at org.springframework.batch.item.xml.StaxEventItemWriter.write(StaxEventItemWriter.java:770)
        at org.springframework.batch.item.xml.StaxEventItemWriter$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$d105dd1.invoke(<generated>)
        at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:771)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:749)
        at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.doProceed(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:136)
        at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.invoke(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:124)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:749)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:691)
        at org.springframework.batch.item.xml.StaxEventItemWriter$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$71be73fd.write(<generated>)
        at com.trax.europeangateway.itemwriter.omegaxml.OmegaXmlFileWriter.write(OmegaXmlFileWriter.java:39)
        at com.trax.europeangateway.itemwriter.omegaxml.OmegaXmlFileWriter$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$48e7f3da.invoke(<generated>)
        at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:771)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:749)
        at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.doProceed(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:136)
        at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.invoke(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:124)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:749)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:691)
        at com.trax.europeangateway.itemwriter.omegaxml.OmegaXmlFileWriter$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$f046e646.write(<generated>)
        at org.springframework.batch.item.support.CompositeItemWriter.write(CompositeItemWriter.java:59)
        at org.springframework.batch.item.support.CompositeItemWriter$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$fd4a76ae.invoke(<generated>)
        at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:771)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:749)
        at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.doProceed(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:136)
        at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.invoke(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:124)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:749)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:691)
        at org.springframework.batch.item.support.CompositeItemWriter$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$35f2661a.write(<generated>)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProcessor.writeItems(SimpleChunkProcessor.java:193)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProcessor.doWrite(SimpleChunkProcessor.java:159)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProcessor.write(SimpleChunkProcessor.java:294)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProcessor.process(SimpleChunkProcessor.java:217)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.ChunkOrientedTasklet.execute(ChunkOrientedTasklet.java:77)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:407)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:331)
        at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:140)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$2.doInChunkContext(TaskletStep.java:273)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.scope.context.StepContextRepeatCallback.doInIteration(StepContextRepeatCallback.java:82)
        at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.getNextResult(RepeatTemplate.java:375)
        at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.executeInternal(RepeatTemplate.java:215)
        at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.iterate(RepeatTemplate.java:145)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep.doExecute(TaskletStep.java:258)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep.execute(AbstractStep.java:208)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler.handleStep(SimpleStepHandler.java:148)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.handleStep(AbstractJob.java:410)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleJob.doExecute(SimpleJob.java:136)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.execute(AbstractJob.java:319)
        at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher$1.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:147)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
        - <0x00000005c2106ac8> (a java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker)
```

#### StaxEventItemWriter config

```html
@JobScope
    @Bean(name = "staxTransactionWriter", destroyMethod="")
    public StaxEventItemWriter<TransactionPositionReport> staxTransactionItemWriter(OmegaXmlHeaderCallBack omegaXmlHeaderCallBack, 
            @Value("#{jobParameters['file.path']}") String path, @Value("#{jobParameters['submission.account']}") String submissionAccount) {
        Resource exportFileResource = new FileSystemResource(fileUtils.getFilePath(path, submissionAccount, Directory.TEMP, true));
 
        OmegaXmlJaxb2Marshaller marshaller = new OmegaXmlJaxb2Marshaller();
        marshaller.setContextPath("com.trax.europeangateway.model.dto.xsd.omega");
        marshaller.setSupportJaxbElementClass(true);
        marshaller.setCheckForXmlRootElement(false);
        
        return new StaxEventItemWriterBuilder<TransactionPositionReport>()
                .name("transactionWriter")
                .resource(exportFileResource)
                .marshaller(marshaller)
                .rootTagName("{http://deutsche-boerse.com/DBRegHub}reportFile")
                .headerCallback(omegaXmlHeaderCallBack)
                .footerCallback(getOmegaXmlFooterCallBack())
                .build();
    }
```

#### Jaxb2Marshaller config

```html
import javax.xml.XMLConstants;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;
import javax.xml.bind.Marshaller;
import javax.xml.namespace.QName;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLEventWriter;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamWriter;
import javax.xml.transform.Result;

import org.springframework.lang.Nullable;
import org.springframework.oxm.XmlMappingException;
import org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller;
import org.springframework.oxm.mime.MimeContainer;
import org.springframework.util.xml.StaxUtils;

import com.trax.europeangateway.model.dto.xsd.omega.ObjectFactory;
import com.trax.europeangateway.model.dto.xsd.omega.TransactionPositionReport;

public class OmegaXmlJaxb2Marshaller extends Jaxb2Marshaller {
    
    @Override
    public void marshal(Object graph, Result result, @Nullable MimeContainer mimeContainer) throws XmlMappingException {
        try {
            Marshaller marshaller = createMarshaller();
            if (StaxUtils.isStaxResult(result)) {
                marshalStaxResult(marshaller, graph, result);
            }
        }
        catch (JAXBException ex) {
            throw convertJaxbException(ex);
        }
    }
    
    private void marshalStaxResult(Marshaller jaxbMarshaller, Object graph, Result staxResult) throws JAXBException {
        XMLStreamWriter streamWriter = StaxUtils.getXMLStreamWriter(staxResult);
        if (streamWriter != null) {
            jaxbMarshaller.marshal(graph, streamWriter);
        }
        else {
            XMLEventWriter eventWriter = StaxUtils.getXMLEventWriter(staxResult);
            if (eventWriter != null) {
                ObjectFactory fact = new ObjectFactory();
                TransactionPositionReport transaction = fact.createTransactionPositionReport();
                transaction.setConfigurableFields(((TransactionPositionReport)graph).getConfigurableFields());
                transaction.setMifir(((TransactionPositionReport)graph).getMifir());
                transaction.setProcessingDetails(((TransactionPositionReport)graph).getProcessingDetails());
                JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(TransactionPositionReport.class);
                Marshaller marshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
                marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
                
                QName qName = new QName(XMLConstants.NULL_NS_URI, "transaction", XMLConstants.DEFAULT_NS_PREFIX);
                JAXBElement<TransactionPositionReport> element = new JAXBElement(qName, TransactionPositionReport.class, TransactionPositionReport.class, transaction);

                marshaller.marshal(element, eventWriter);
            }
            else {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("StAX Result contains neither XMLStreamWriter nor XMLEventConsumer");
            }
        }
    }

}
```

### Observation

If I `reduce` the `chunk batch size` from `500` to `100`, wait is `reduced to 2 minutes(approx)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That the time the writer needs scales with the chunk size, suggests that the writer is really inefficient at writing each item.

If your stack trace is similar every time you check, then the root cause for this is the call of `JAXBContext::newInstance` in `OmegaXmlJaxb2Marshaller::marshalStaxResult`. Creating a new marshaller for every item to be written is too much overhead.

You should move the code block

```
JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(TransactionPositionReport.class);
Marshaller marshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
```

to the constructor of `OmegaXmlJaxb2Marshaller` and make `marshaller` an instance variable.

Then, the marshaller will only be created once and the writer should be much faster.